# PDO Prepare literal

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement, prepare

Let's say I have a very basic update query:

```
$sql = 'UPDATE `table` SET column = :value WHERE id = :id';
```

I prepare this with PDO and I can set the column "column" to any value. Good this works well.

I can very easily use this prepared statement to set column to a specific value:

```
 UPDATE `table` SET column = 12 WHERE id = 123
```

However, what If I want to run the query:

```
 'UPDATE `table` SET column = column + 1 WHERE id = 123
```

Is this possible using the same prepared statement? I'm guessing not, which is a shame because it's probably not worth using prepared statements as I don't know exactly how the value for column will be calculated.

e.g. $stmt->execute(array(':value' => 'column + 1', ':id' => 123));

Comment: It's not possible with the same prepared statement. You should determine the setting/incremental logic before preparing the statement

Comment: It's not possible to use prepared statements for this. You'd have to inject it directly into the query

Comment: Why don't you try it before asking

Comment: I had tried but wasn't aware if there was some special syntax to achieve this. My goal was to minimise the number of queries. Either I can fetch the existing value for $column or I can prepare a second update which includes the logic. Is either of these preferred? Either way it invloves another query.

Answer (score 0):

You could use it through a loop:

```
$column = 12;
$params = array(':value' => $column, ':id' => 123);

for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    $params[':value'] = '' . $column + $i; // string, not integer!

    $stmt->execute($params);
}
```

Comment: That's fine, but I already need to have fetched the value of $column from the database. If i'm running a second query, I may as well just prepare a second update query. I was trying to minimise the number of queries.

Answer (score 0):

I see no problem here.
Why can't you just prepare and execute the following query when you need it?

```
UPDATE `table` SET column = column + 1 WHERE id = ?
```

and this one

```
UPDATE `table` SET column = column - 1 WHERE id = ?
```

when you need to subtract?

Do you have [not imaginary but a real life-based] case which puts you in a fix?
It pretty sure there is an elegant solution

Comment: That works fine, but it defeats the purpose of preparing the query in the first place if you're not going to re-use the prepared statement. I was attempting to minimise the amount of work involved. In my real world scenario I'll need to prepare a different query for each updates, which is what I was trying to avoid.

Comment: Yes, that's the point. Prepared statements are pointless most of time. The only their use is security, yet one can have the same level of security even without them.